# Defining certain tables in JavaScript switch based on ID and attributes

Tags: javascript, jquery, asp.net, html, asp.net-mvc-3

In my project we have a file 'permissionType.js' which determines the current user's permission role and restricts certain functionality accordingly. This is done by applying an attribute `data-projectsecurity` to each area it is suited for and with the following script which runs when this is encountered. We want it so that users who are not in the correct role do not have the ability to delve into a table entry, as the `onclick` attribute is removed.

Please see the code below:

```
checkPermission = function () {
    $('[data-projectsecurity]').each(function () {
        var id = $(this)[0].id;
        var node = $(this)[0];
        var notInRole = true;
        if (objPermission) {
            $.each(objPermission, function (i, v) {
                if (v == node.getAttribute('data-projectsecurity')) {
                    notInRole = false;
                };
            });
            if (notInRole) {
                switch (node.nodeName) {
                    case 'TR':
                        $(node).removeAttr("onclick");
                        break;
                    case 'TD':
                        $(node).removeAttr("onclick");
                        break;
                };
            };
        }
    });
```

The question I pose is how would I best apply this to only tables of a certain ID that possess the `data-projectsecurity` attribute. Say for instance if I only wanted this to affect rows in tables with the ID `transactionTable` and `ownerTable` would it be a matter of creating an if statement in the switch?

Something akin to `if ($(id)) { $(node).removeAttr("onclick") };` with the id being `#transactionTable tr.data-bancpaysecurity` to select rows in the `transactionTable` with the security attribute.

```
case 'TR':
    if ($('#transactionTable tr.data-projectsecurity')) 
    {
        $(node).removeAttr("onclick");
    }
```

And here is an example of a table entry where the attribute is applied:

```
    <td style="@numericStyle" data-projectsecurity = "@PermissionType.ViewTransaction.ToString()" onclick="window.location='/Transaction/ViewCIPS/@trnId'">@val</td>
```

Sorry if this seems overly convoluted, but hopefully you can see what I'm aiming for! Please let me know if you require any more information on the issue and thank you so much to anyone who offers their help.

Comment: If data-projectsecurity is attribute, use `if ($('#transactionTable tr[data-projectsecurity]').length > 0)` as condition instead of `if ($('#transactionTable tr.data-projectsecurity'))`

Comment: @codefreak is correct, however you should really be limiting the use of javascript to impose security in this manner. After just reading over what you have so far, I could quickly hack your application to see into the very stuff you are trying to hide from me. Server side permissions are much better for this type of work.

Comment: Thank you both for your comments, I will implement this now and feed back. I have mentioned that to my team myself, but we do have server side permissions so not to worry. This is really just to restrict the functionality on the front end, so even if they were to disable the script they wouldn't be able to access the page. Thanks a lot though!